# Issues in UINavigationController in Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am working in iPhone application, Using `XCode 4.3.2` tool develop my application (not using story board). When I press a button from `homescreen.m` to navigate to Login screen, then I run the app, cannot navigate from home to login screen, how to fix this issue?
**I tried this:**

Class Name - `Appdelegate.m`

```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    home = [[HomeScreen alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navi =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];
    [self.window addSubview:navi.view];
    return YES;
}
```

Class Name - HomeScreen.m

```
#import "HomeScreen.h"
#import "LoginScreen.h"

@interface HomeScreen ()

@end

@implementation HomeScreen

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"HomeScreen";

    UIButton *Button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    Button1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 50);
    [Button1 setTitle:@"Homescreen" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(GotONext) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:Button1]; 
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void)GotONext
{
    LoginScreen *log =[[LoginScreen alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:log animated:YES];
}
```

Class Name - LoginScreen.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"LoginScreen";


}
```

[image]

Comment: make navigation controller a property and try retaining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try bellow code...

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
home = [[[HomeScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *navviewController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: HomeScreen];
self.window.rootViewController = navviewController1;
    return YES;
}
```

and on next button method use bellow code...

```
-(void)GotONext
{
    LoginScreen *log =[[LoginScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:log animated:YES];
}
```

i hope this help you...

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgot this thing to write initwithNibName:@"LogonScreen".

```
-(void)GotONext
{
    LoginScreen *log =[[LoginScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:log animated:YES];
}
```